# Haskell : If the input fails validation, i want it to ask for the same input again

Tags: haskell

```
registerUser1  userDb =
  putStrLn "Enter the email " >>  getLine >>= \email -> 
    putStrLn "Enter the name " >> getLine >>= \name ->
      putStrLn "Enter the password " >> getLine >>= \password ->
        putStrLn "Enter the postal code " >> getLine >>= \postalcode -> 
          let newuser = MkNewUser{nuserEmail = MkEmail email, nuserFullName = name, nuserPassword = password, nuserPostalCode = postalcode}
              output =   (registerUser newuser userDb)
          in case output of
                Left err -> putStrLn err >> registerUser1 userDb
                Right udb -> pure udb
```

If i enter a name and if it fails a validate function, i want the user to reenter the name until it passes the validate function. How can i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `getLine` to get the name, you can use a helper function which repeats until a valid name is entered.

```
getName = do
  putStrLn "Enter the name"
  name <- getLine
  if null name  -- Replace with your own validation.
    then do
      putStrLn "Invalid name"
      getName
    else pure name
```

This can also be defined locally in a `let` binding or `where` clause. And if you’re going to be performing validation on all these fields, it would pay to abstract the helper to take the prompt and validation function as arguments:

```
getParameter label valid = loop
  where
    loop = do
      putStrLn $ "Enter the " ++ label
      value <- getLine
      if valid value
        then pure value
        else do
          putStrLn $ "Invalid value for " ++ label
          loop
```

You can also use `do` notation to make the definition of `registerUser1` less noisy and nested—it desugars to the same code you’ve written above.

```
registerUser1 userDb = do
  putStrLn "Enter the email"
  email <- getLine
  putStrLn "Enter the name"
  name <- getName
  putStrLn "Enter the password"
  password <- getLine
  putStrLn "Enter the postal code"
  postalcode <- getLine
  let
    newuser = MkNewUser
      { nuserEmail = MkEmail email
      , nuserFullName = name
      , nuserPassword = password
      , nuserPostalCode = postalcode
      }
    output = registerUser newuser userDb
  case output of
    Left err -> do
      putStrLn err
      registerUser1 userDb
    Right udb -> pure udb
```

With the above helper function:

```
registerUser1 userDb = do
  email <- getParameter "email" validEmail
  name <- getParameter "name" validName
  password <- getParameter "password" validPassword
  postalcode <- getParameter "postal code" validPostalCode
  …
```